# How to get the relative Enum from a value as param?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums

I have enum like :

```
class enum ErrorType(value:String){
     TYPE_A("typeA"), TYPE_B("typeB"), TYPE_C("typeC"), UNKNOWN("unknown")
}
```

I want to get the appropriate Enum relative to the value given, for example :

```
val errorType = ErrorType.valueOf("typeB")
```

but it returns an exception. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Can you try `val errorType = ErrorType.valueOf(ErrorType.class ,"typeB")`

Comment: @TDIScott the function accept only 1 param (String)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`valueOf` finds the Enum by its instance name, which in your example is `"TYPE_B"`, not `"typeB"`.

To use the `value` property to find the associated Enum, you have to manually do the search. There's no built-in shortcut for this because the compiler doesn't know how the properties of any particular Enum will be used.

```
val errorType = ErrorType.values().first { it.value == "typeB" }
```

If you want to have `UNKNOWN` be a fallback for invalid Strings instead of throwing:

```
val errorType = ErrorType.values().firstOrNull { it.value == "typeB" } ?: ErrorType.UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Personally whenever I have to do a lookup, I usually end up making a function with an automatically generated map of properties to enums (``lazy`` is good for this). ``values()`` creates a new array every time it's called, which may or may not be a problem for you!

Comment: For an enum with fewer than a couple dozen values, perhaps the fastest solution is to lazily create a persistent values array but still use a direct search of that array instead of a map.

Answer (score 1):

Please send minimal compilable code  - `class enum ErrorType` is no  valid java code.

Provided your constructor parameter value is backed by a private member errorValue, in your enum you could implement a static method

```
public static ErrorType getValueOf(String value){
    for(ErrorType et:ErrorType.values()){
        if(et.errorValue.equals(value){
            return et;
        }
     }
     return ErrorType.UNKOWN;
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, sorry, i didn't see the kotlin tag on this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

> The valueOf() method throws an IllegalArgumentException if the specified name does not match any of the enum constants defined in the class.

But, this method should be match with the name of the Enum, so you should be call this method something like this:

```
val errorType = ErrorType.valueOf("TYPE_B")
```

you should be call this method with the `name` instead of it's `parameter`.

Comment: I can not change the value structure due its aleady defined !

Answer (score 0):

I use a lookup method (I use it so much I have it as a template:))

```
public enum ErrorType
{
    TYPE_A("typeA"),
    TYPE_B("typeB"),
    TYPE_C("typeC"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    private String ivLookup;

    private ErrorType( String lookup )
    {
        ivLookup = lookup;
    }

    public String getLookup()
    {
        return ivLookup;
    }

    /**
     * Return the enum value for the given lookup key
     */
    public static ErrorType getErrorType( String lookUp ) throws EnumNotFoundException
    {
        if (lookUp != null)
            for (ErrorType type : ErrorType.values())
                if (type.getLookup().equals( lookUp ))
                    return type;

        throw new EnumNotFoundException( ErrorType.class.getName(), lookUp );
    }
}
```

The `EnumNotFoundException` is my own.

If you don't want the overhead of looping through the enum values, and/or you have a lot of enum values:

```
public enum ErrorType
{
    TYPE_A("typeA"),
    TYPE_B("typeB"),
    TYPE_C("typeC"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    private String                            ivLookup;
    private static HashMap<String, ErrorType> ivMap = null;

    private ErrorType( String lookup )
    {
        ivLookup = lookup;
    }

    public String getLookup()
    {
        return ivLookup;
    }

    /**
     * Return the enum value for the given lookup key
     */
    public static ErrorType getErrorType( String lookUp ) throws EnumNotFoundException
    {
        ErrorType errorType = null;

        if (ivMap == null)
        {
            ivMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (ErrorType type : ErrorType.values())
                ivMap.put( type.getLookup(), type );
        }

        errorType = ivMap.get( lookUp );

        if (errorType != null)
            return errorType;

        throw new EnumNotFoundException( ErrorType.class.getName(), lookUp );
    }
}
```

And you use it:

```
ErrorType errorType = ErrorType.getErrorType("typeB");
```

With a try/catch of course